# Regular expression for splitting a String while preserving whitespace

Tags: java, android, regex

I am doing an Android project which needs to split a String into tokens while **preserving** whitespaces and also not to split at non-word characters like `#`, `&` etc ...

Using `\b` splits at any non-word character .So i need a way to split the string in the following way.

Input: (`.` indicates whitespace)

```
A.A#..A##
```

Desired output:

```
A
.
A#
..
A##
```

So these 5 lines are the 5 values I would like in an array or similar. That means the 4th element of the result-array contains 2 spaces.

Comment: whats wrong with splitting based on `\\s+` ?. [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/nN9uZ9/1)

Comment: I believe \\s+ does not preserve whitespaces.

Comment: But where are you preserving whitespaces in your output?

Comment: Sorry my mistake.I have edited the output part.

Comment: To confirm/clarify: the 5 lines in your _Output:_ are the 5 values you would want in an array-type object right? And the dots aren't actual dots, they are spaces replaced with dots to make them visible for this question, right? If so then I don't think commenters/answerers (other than me ;) ) were getting that.

Comment: @funkwurm Yes ,that's right.Glad you got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
(?<=\S)(?=\s)|(?<=\s)(?=\S)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/9aeSalo_vkADv9il)

Basically I'm saying "if the previous character is a non-space and the next is a space **or** if the previous is a space and the next is a non-space, then split".

Comment: Can i use this regex in java?I'm confused what the symbols "<" does.note:I'm weak in regex.

Comment: Java is not my best language, but looking at some other answers it should be something like `String[] res = str.split("(?<=\S)(?=\s)|(?<=\s)(?=\S)");` The `(?<=...)` part is the "if preceded by" part you see in the visualization, it's also called a **[Negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)**

Comment: Ah you probably have to escape the slashes then, so `String[] res = str.split("(?<=\\S)(?=\\s)|(?<=\\s)(?=\\S)");`

Answer (score 1):

Use StringTokenizer:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("A.A#..A##", ".");//first argument is string you want to split, another is whitespace

while(st.hasMoreTokens())
  System.out.println(st.nextToken());
```

output will be:
    A
    A#
    A##

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`String s = "A.A#..A##";`
`if(s.contains("..")) | s.contains("...")) {
 s.replace("..", ".");
 s.replace("...", ".");
String out[] = s.split(".");`

It should give you an array with Strings the way you want :)

Don't forget to replace the "." with actual spaces :)

Comment: You did not understand my question. Its my mistake ,i should learn to describe better.I used "." to indicate whitespaces.The whitespaces could be spaces of any number.But consecutive whitespaces should be treated as a whole and splitted. I'm not sure if i'm making any sense. :)

Comment: Ok, that was difficult to understand - for me, at least